# unable to validate directory loaded from property file

Tags: java, windows, file, io

I am trying to load a directory from a properties file.  I have the following defined in the property file:

```
image.src.dir = "C:\\Temp\\foo\\"
```

Yes, the directory name is like that ... with mixed case.  I have also tried simply referring to the directory as `"/Temp/foo"` with the same outcome.

I have the following code which fails despite the directory existing.

```
String srcDir = prop.getProperty("image.src.dir");

File folder = new File(srcDir);
if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
System.err.println("Directory: " + srcDir + " doesn't exist");
}
```

Thanks for the hint ...

The problem & solution:

**solution:** `image.src.dir=C:\\Temp\\foo\\`

**problem:** `image.src.dir = "C:\\Temp\\foo\\"`

That was my problem ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to System.println(srcDir) if the string gets properly loaded from the properties file? Is the directory accessible (are the rights for superdirectories correct?).

Comment: 1.  Directory: "C:\Temp\foo\" doesn't exist .... is what is printed.  2.  it's windows with no funniness on the dirs.

Comment: and in that breath ... that gave me the answer.  problem is how the property was defined.  Doh!

Answer (score 2):

You have quotes in your property file.  Quotes are needed for literal Strings in Java, but not Strings defined inside of a properties file.

Try this:

```
image.src.dir = C:\\Temp\\foo\\
```

Comment: Actually, image.src.dir = C:\\Temp\\foo\\ didn't work.  Removing the spaces between dir = C: fixed it.  My problems switching between Java / PHP / Javascript....